# How to catch SignalR client messages when one of my hub method is in a Thread.Sleep delay?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have two hub methods for a question and answer quiz style game.
One hub method sends questions to clients and one method collects the answers.
SendQuestion method is a for loop question sender. In the loop sends the question to Clients.All.QuestionReceived methods and wait for 10 seconds to answer clients by running System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000).
After the sleep, then read the static list answer array for the correct answers.

The other SendAnswer method collects the answers and store them in the static answer array.

I have a problem when I want to calculate correct answers after the thread sleep. But the array is empty.
When the for loop ends, then all the answers is triggered by SendAnswer and stored in the array. But it is to late to calculate them.

How can I get the answers of this answers in a running for loop method running.

For my example code; one of the admin if send Start message, then hub start sending messages to clients.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public static List<string> mesajlar = new List<string>();
    public void SendAnswer(string username, string message)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(username + " - SendAnswer - " + message);
        mesajlar.Add(message);
    }

    public void SendMessage(string username, string message)
    {
        if (message == "Start")
        {
            Clients.All.MessageReceived(username, "Sleep BEGIN");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 20);
            Clients.All.MessageReceived(username, "Sleep END");
            foreach (var s in mesajlar)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(s);
            }
        } else
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(username + " - SendMessage - " + message);
            mesajlar.Add(message);
        }
        Clients.All.MessageReceived(username, message);
    }

    public void SendQuestion(string question, string answer1, string answer2, string answer3)
    {
        Clients.All.QuestionReceived(question, answer1, answer2, answer3);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is why are you using sleep? It will block the current thread.

Comment: I want to wait clients answer in a standart time

Comment: NEVER use Thread.Sleep in a production app. Its meant for simulating lengthy operations while testing/debugging on an MTA thread. In .NET there is no other reason to use it. Use a Queue for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. Is this URL is a good place to start? https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-status-background-job-signalr/

Comment: Yes it's pretty good. I actually like Hangfire for things like this, but it's a good start.